# Git: show more context when using git add -i or git add -e?

Tags: git

I'm selectively committing parts of a large file and I'd like to see more context around each hunk. Is this possible?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Short answer: no.

`git diff` has the `-U<n>` option which allows you to customize the number of lines to show around a change. For example, `git diff -U5 ...` will show 5 lines of context. As far as I can tell, there is no such option available for the diff display in the interactive mode.

Comment: Is there a `-U<infinity>` option to show the whole file?  (Or is a large number "good enough"?)

Comment: I'd like to mention that the number in `git diff -U<n>` is used on both sides of each changed line. So if you have one line changed, `git diff -U5` will show you 11 lines (assuming the one line isn't at the start of end of the file.)

Comment: This is for `git diff` not for `git add --patch` or `git add --interactive`

Comment: @titaniumdecoy, I posted that as a separate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727424/for-git-diff-is-there-a-uinfinity-option-to-show-the-whole-file

Comment: Still no solution?

Answer (score 12):

This is possible using the GIT_DIFF_OPTS environment variable.

For example:

```
GIT_DIFF_OPTS=-u10 git add -p
```

will display 10 lines of context.

See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_diffing_and_merging .

Comment: Note this also works with `git show`.

Answer (score 4):

To confirm, this is still not possible in 2019.

An external tool like [`jjlee/git-meld-index`](https://github.com/jjlee/git-meld-index) can help:

> `git-meld-index` runs `meld` -- or any other git difftool (`kdiff3`, `diffuse`, etc.) -- to allow you to interactively stage changes to the git index (also known as the git staging area).

This is similar to the functionality of `git add -p`, and `git add --interactive`.

> In some cases meld is easier / quicker to use than `git add -p` or the staging feature in tools like `git gui`.
>   That's because meld allows you, for example, to:
>
> - **see more context**,
> - see intra-line diffs
> - edit by hand and see 'live' diff updates (updated after every keypress)
> - navigate to a change without saying '`n`' to every change you want to skip

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add that you can get the diff with full context using a solution like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683517/15410684 by Ezra.

```
git diff -U$(wc -l MYFILE)
```

gets you pretty close