# Git : See modified lines in Sublime text

Tags: git

How do i see modified lines inside Sublime text 3

Comment: What's wrong with `git diff`?

Comment: it is not clean for big files and i see characters like ^M... wish i had enough reputation to share image.. Here is something i seee  !DOCTYPE HTML>^M^M<html>^M^M<head>^M^M<meta charset="utf-8">^M^M<title>4Hire Inc</title>^M^M<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">^M^M^M<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">^M<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap-theme.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"

Comment: The `^M` is the difference between linux and windows line endings. To ignore these use `git diff --ignore-space-at-eol`.

Comment: even above command shows same characters ^M .. image attached

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889559/git-diff-to-ignore-m)

Comment: Thanks but even after  " git config --global core.autocrlf true" ,  i get ^M when i do "git diff"

Comment: ^M in the diff are not random, they are there for a reason. They mean that your editor is set up to use different line endings comparing to the original file and can't preserve them. Set up your editor to use correct line endings and don't try to hide this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved using [Git Gutter](https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter)

Install Git gutter in Sublime text 3:

```
cd ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages

git clone git://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter.git
```

By default, Git Gutter compares your working copy against the HEAD. You can change this behaviour through the ST command palette. The following options are available:

1. Compare against **HEAD**
2. Compare against particular **branch**
3. Compare against particular **tag**
4. Compare against specific **commit**

To change the compare option:

Open the command palette (`Ctrl-Shift-P` for Windows/Linux, `Cmd-Shift-P` for Mac)
Start typing `GitGutter`
You'll see the 4 options listed above, select one with the keyboard.
Choose the branch/tag/commit to compare against.

[To the left of line numbers we can see the changes add/updated/deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK1A0.png)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but Sublime offers the `subl -` command for piping output into a new tab.

```
git diff | subl -
```

P.S. To show the full file (including unchanged lines), you could try the command given from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627598/how-to-get-git-diff-with-full-context/40683517#40683517):

```
git diff -U$(wc -l MYFILE) MYFILE | subl -
```