# Increase git hunk granularity

Tags: git

I usually add changes with `git add -p`, and many times there are large hunks with several blocks of code, separated by blank lines.

However, git won't `split` the hunk any further, and I have to resort to manual editing.

How can I increase the granularity of the hunks, such that every block of code will be in a separate hunk?

Edit: This is a different question from [Git: show more context when using git add -i or git add -e?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711670/git-show-more-context-when-using-git-add-i-or-git-add-e), since I'M not looking to increase the context around each hunk, but rather increase the number of hunks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It cant be done,

These are the options you can do within `add -p`:

```
y - stage this hunk
n - do not stage this hunk
q - quit, do not stage this hunk nor any of the remaining ones
a - stage this and all the remaining hunks in the file
d - do not stage this hunk nor any of the remaining hunks in the file
g - select a hunk to go to
/ - search for a hunk matching the given regex
j - leave this hunk undecided, see next undecided hunk
J - leave this hunk undecided, see next hunk
k - leave this hunk undecided, see previous undecided hunk
K - leave this hunk undecided, see previous hunk
s - split the current hunk into smaller hunks
e - manually edit the current hunk
? - print help
```

Once you use the `s` it will pick the chunk of code which can be considered as a standalone change. If you want to split it even more you will have to use the `e` to edit the hunk and then add it back to the stage area.

#### Summary:

To split hunks you use the `s` flag.
If you need to split it into even smaller chunks you will need to manually edit it using the `e` option.

[image]

Comment: Thx, but I'M well aware of how `add -p` works, and I'M looking for a workaround without resorting to manual editing.

Comment: @dimid: The answer is "can't be done", and I'm afraid you insisting you want to do it won't help.

Answer (score 4):

As @codeWizard [said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34610928/4433386), git just doesn't support what you want, and it hence can't be done in `git add`.

Now, you could write a script yourself that does the following:

1. copy your locally changed version of to somewhere outside the tree
2. `git checkout -- <changedfile>` to bring your modified file to an unmodified state
3. write a user interface of your own to select ranges in the file that you want to add now
4. add the modifications to the in-tree .
5. git commit
6. If desirable, go to 3. again

Answer (score 2):

`git gui` lets you select specific lines to stage.

Open `git gui` in your git repository, then right click on the desired line > "Stage Line For Commit".

Now, it will not let you edit a file (I wish it could open a temporary file in your favorite editor). To work around this, you can simply mark the commit message with a reminder:

```
AMENDME: Add x
do not forget to rename thing
```

When you are done with your coding stretch, you can use `git rebase -i <original branch>`, mark the "AMENDME" commit with the `edit` command and amend that commit.

Comment: I strongly disagree. My development platform cannot be simpler: a text editor (emacs) and the git command line utility. I sometimes use `git gui` et al. to review and work out hairier commits; when I spot a typo, it's a bit of a pain to go back to my editor just to correct it, when it could do that for me.

Comment: I don't see the point in committing and amending. It is lengthy.