# How to interactively commit with git CLI, similar to the one here in hg CLI?

Tags: git, mercurial

I'm looking for a solution very close to the usage with mercurial, as seen below. I have tried `git add -p`, `git add -e`, `git add --interactive`, `tig` and few others.

I've also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085162/commit-only-part-of-a-file-in-git) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609924/increase-git-hunk-granularity).

However these methods prove to be cumbersome and annoying when I have to do this across multiple hunks over different files.

Note that GUI is not an option.

Edit-1: I've tried vim fugitive and can't select hunks like this in fugitive as well.

Edit-2: Removed comparison with hg.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm getting down voted. It's a genuine question. How are git users doing this?

Comment: I don’t see a question. Apart from making a statement about mercurial having a better interactive hunk adding, what is your question?

Comment: My question is about how to get a ncurses interface in git to select the hunks from multiple different files at once.  Whoever I talked to about git goes on to say use `git add -p`. The mercurial example was provided as a way to relate how it does to show people what I actually mean.

Comment: The previous suggestions is how to do it natively in git. Anything else close to what you want is likely to be provided by another tool, which is sadly off topic for SO, but I’d love to know what you find.

Comment: Downvote from me: It is impossible to deduce *from the text* what is really the intention of the question. Having to look at a video which is only slightly relevant AND to extract the relevant parts from there -- really ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew Shadura's [crecord extension](https://github.com/andrewshadura/git-crecord) is exactly what I was looking for.

Set it up as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/andrewshadura/git-crecord
cd git-crecord
./setup.py install
ln -s $PWD/git-crecord ~/.local/bin/git-crecord
```

cd to your git repo and invoke it as follows:

```
git crecord
```

This would bring up the ncurses interface which can be used as shown below. Pressing the following keys in the ncurses window will do certain actions:

```
f       hunk toggle fold (arrow keys can also be used)
space   toggle hunk selection
a       toggle commit or amend
c       confirm and open commit window
```

[image]

Comment: Glad you found what you were looking for. In future please note that asking for a plug-in is off topic.